# How to stop PHP errors (notices, warnings, deprecation, etc) from showing on front end?

Tags: 9

PHP erros (they are all actually deprecation warnings) are appearing on many pages of the site, and I've done all the recommended things to turn them off:

- display_errors is "Off" (checked with phpinfo())
- `drush site:mode` is set to `prod`
- On the "Logging and Errors" page, "None" is ticked.

What else is there to do?

The errors/warnings - with full stack trace - appear even for anonymous users. I don't want them to appear for anyone, and I would have expected the settings detailed above to achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide errors from users but show to admin?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36192/hide-errors-from-users-but-show-to-admin)

Comment: Never seen an option in Drupal to enable deprecation warnings. How did you do that?

Comment: @4uk4 I should have said PHP error messages/notices/warnings... It's just that they mostly happen to be deprecation warnings because it's on PHP8.1. But all PHP error messages really

Comment: @leymannx thanks for the suggestion but no. I don't want them to display for anyone. Also that question is for Drupal 7

Comment: The accepted answer names a module compatible with Drupal 9 you can use to disable/configure error messages.

Comment: @leymannx I see. Well, I could use that if necessary. But I would prefer to get to the bottom of the issue. Why are these PHP errors showing when they are turned off in all places? There is something wrong with the site, and I want to solve the problem rather than add another module. Thanks!

Comment: The bottom of the issue is that you need to fix the actual errors by either updating the affected modules or downgrading PHP. The messages are just a symptom.

Comment: @leymannx firsly, the errors are coming from Drupal core. Secondly, the settings I detailed in the answer ought to stop them. Thanks for your help but I am looking for someone who can give me a different perspective on this,

Comment: @naomi, nevermind, I was thinking about Drupal deprecations. Now that you've changed the title it's clear they are PHP warnings. - If *On the "Logging and Errors" page, "None" is ticked* doesn't help, I guess you have overridden the config option somewhere: `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';`

Comment: Woohoo thanks @4uk4! That solved it. That line was there in settings.php, and deleting it and a drush cr sorted it. If you feel like adding that as an answer of course I'll give it a tick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

- On the "Logging and Errors" page, "None" is ticked.

doesn't help, look for this line

```
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
```

This is discussed since 2015 whether you should be able to see in UI that your choice is overridden. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2621920.